# How to disable swipe in Android Image Slider (daimajia)

Tags: android, slider, swipe, swipe-gesture

I have a slider with daimajia like this

```
<com.daimajia.slider.library.SliderLayout
                    android:id="@+id/bsNews"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:background="@drawable/bck_rounded"
                    custom:indicator_visibility="invisible"
                    custom:pager_animation_span="1100"/>
```

and i want the slider to auto-cycle, but we wouldn't touch it and disable swipe left and right in slider.
can help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach can be : that you need to **extend** existing functionality([SliderLayout](https://github.com/daimajia/AndroidImageSlider/blob/master/library/src/main/java/com/daimajia/slider/library/SliderLayout.java)) and change it to **receive touch events** and do nothing on those touches.

Can you think along these lines?

If you are still confused, check out [this original answer to a similar query](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/622955/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D1%83-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0).